# Why do we drink clean water

Tags: human-biology, immunology, limnology

Most of the street/feral animals (cats, dogs, cows, some wild animals too) drink tap water or dirty water, but it doesnt seem to affect them. So, why do humans drink pure water?

Comment: We can drink dirty water, and have through much of history (until we discovered fermentation and later, sanitation). Dirty water is bad for you regardless though. That's part of why we live to 80+ these days, but died younger in the past. You'd probably find you'd be even more ill from drinking unclean water nowadays vs several hundreds/thousands of years back (in the West at least) since our levels of hygiene have reduced our immunity to many of the nasties in dirty water

Comment: @JoeHealey - Or, many of the nasties in the water now weren't yet invented by man. It's not only bacteria that pollutes.